# SQL Solution for calculating aggregated consumption from incremental values on a real time basis

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression, database-trigger, sql-view

I have a SQL table where column that has incremental values per second. 
How could I determine the change or consumption value for an hour ?

```
For e.g.
Date            Time                EnergyKWH
2019-02-16      18:00:00.000        43.366
2019-02-16      18:00:01.000        43.367
2019-02-16      18:00:02.000        43.369
.................
............
.........
2019-02-16      19:00:00.000        70.886
```

(1 record for every 1 second, 3600 in 1 hour)

How can I find the Total consumption per hourly basis, from 18:00 to 19:00, and have this calculated for all the 24 hours separately? (The hourly consumption will be the difference between 18:00 and 19:00 values).

```
Expected Result :
Date            StartTime           EndTime             EnergyKWH
2019-02-16      18:00:00            19:00:00            27.250        (Difference of 70.886-43.366)
2019-02-16      19:00:00            20:00:00            21.561        (Next Value Approximation)
```

The data is coming in live on a per second basis, and I need a solution that could automate this process.

> Should I be looking at using something like a View or a CTE for on the fly calculation or maybe a Trigger with computed results going to another table holding my required result set ?

Please bear in mind that this will be a continual process for all dates, and all 24 hours. I would ideally like to hold at least 7 days of the computed/result data. My DB version is MS SQL 2012.

I just need the difference in the value at 18:00 and 19:00, and similarly for all 24 hours, for today and any date in the past.

> I can do that calculation mathematically, its very easy, but what would be an optimal way to automate that process as new data continues to flow in ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff.  SQL 2012

Comment: What are the data types of the columns?

Comment: Date, Time, and Decimal.

Comment: Just to reiterate, the data is coming in at a frequency of 1 second, and i need the total value consumed in 1 hour. @GordonLinoff : You solution is calculating the difference in the per second values. I changed it to Datepart(Hour), still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all data with no gaps, then something like this:

```
select t.date, t.time as starttime,
       lead(t.time) over (order by t.date, t.time) as endtime,
       (lead(EnergyKWH) over (order by t.date, t.time) -
        EnergyKWH
       ) as EnergyKWH_diff
from t
where extract(minute from time) = 0
order by t.date, t.time;
```

This uses ISO/ANSI standard functions.  These may differ by database, but the idea is the same.

In SQL Server, this would be expressed as:

```
select t.date, t.time as starttime,
       lead(t.time) over (order by t.date, t.time) as endtime,
       (lead(EnergyKWH) over (order by t.date, t.time) -
        EnergyKWH
       ) as EnergyKWH_diff
from t
where datepart(minute, time) = 0
order by t.date, t.time;
```

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get this to work. Its calculating it on a minute basis, and giving me 0 values.

Comment: Sample result :

Comment: Date   ,starttime  ,endtime ,  EnergyKWH_diff

Comment: 2019-02-16 , 01:00:00.000 ,01:00:01.000, 0.000

Comment: 2019-02-16 , 01:00:01.000 ,01:00:02.000 ,0.000

Comment: I am using the datepart() since extract doesn't seem to be available in sql 2012

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have a possible solution, but I don't want to go with this because its very crude and very slow.

Its taking >5 secs for 7 days data, this will continue to increase as the data expands.

Will creating a View or a CTE help give better performance ?
I know I could add an additional index in a View, but isn't a CTE better since I am hitting the table recursively (Self join will replace this nested query)

Sample Solution Query :

```
SELECT 
    (CASE WHEN ((DATEPART(Minute,p.[Time])) = 0 AND (DATEPART(SECOND,p.Time)) = 0)
                AND (DateAdd(HOUR,1, p.[Time])  IS NOT NULL)
        THEN 
             (Select -1 * (p.EnergyKWH - (Select EnergyKWH from FactPLCDetails p2 WHERE p2.[Time] = (DateAdd(HOUR,1, p.[Time])) AND p.[Date] = p2.[Date]) ))
        END
    )
    as [EnergyDiff],
    p.[Time] As Start_Time,
    (DateAdd(HOUR,1, p.[Time])) as End_Time,
    p.[Date]     
from FactPLCDetails p
ORDER BY [EnergyDiff] DESC
```